# Specify ant target during Teamcity build run

Tags: testing, deployment, ant, build, teamcity

I am trying to set up a Teamcity build configuration that runs from our build.xml ant script.

The ant script contains various targets:

```
<target name="compile"> ... </target>
<target name="package" depends="compile"> ... </target>
<target name="test" depends="package"> ... </target>
<target name="deploy" depends="test"> ... </target>
```

My intention is to have the build run the `test` target a couple of time first (until we get the build right) and then call the `deploy` target to upload the (now tested project) on our production server.

How can I set the Teamcity configuration settings so I can have a `Testing build` and a separate `Deploy build`?

- Is there a way to prompt the user for the ant target (display a list of targets and select the appropriate one)

or

- I have to create a separate Teamcity Build configuration (a copy of the test configuration with the only difference being on the ant target)?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create more build configurations.

Comment: I ended up creating a Template Configuration and specifying a Configuration parameter `%ANT_TARGET%` in the "Target" parameter of the "Ant Parameters" in the "Build Step: Ant" configuration section of the Template Configuration.

Then I created two Build Configurations that depend on the Template Configuration and in their "Properties and Environment Variables" configuration steps I created separate %ANT_TARGET% Configuration parameters (with my two separate ant targets)

Maybe there is a nicer way to do it, but at least this way I get my job done.